# Respond 200 with error or the response code as the error code

Tags: rest, http, api-design

So, being a developer I have a very basic question, in a **REST standard** we have **100's of error code for specific reason** like:

1. 4xx if resource related
2. 5xx if exception occurred in server

and many more.

Now when it comes to the implementation there are situations when we **return 404 directly** as the **response status code** **with the error message in the response body**. With this approach there is a thing that I think a bit confusing, what **if the URI itself is never being made**, that means **suppose /a/b is not implemented** and being any server they respond 404, and **as a client** they check the code and say that the **user** is not found if they are searching for the user with this API.

Instead what I feel (correct me if I am wrong) is that **if the call is successfully completed in the server** (without any exceptions and errors) we return 200 and in the response body return in a specific format like:

```
{
   "status" : boolean, // if the overall call succeeded
   "message" : string, // message from server
   "code" : integer, // code, http code or business level code 
   "data" : object,//actual data
   "type" : string, // type of the data like object, basic, array,  (basically a value from enum)
}
```

The response code of any call will always be 200, with the specific code being available in **code** key of the response format.

Now coming to the usage of these REST call from client prospective, in the client whether it is **browser, IOS, Android or Desktop app**, we call the API and **check for 200** as the **Response code** and all our further functionality will be dependent on **status** & **code** key of the response body itself. Again **if the Response Code itself is not 200** then that it actually the problem with respect to the server.

Coming to the SDK implementations of the API's, we can do the same inside of them, by always checking the **status** and **code** if Response Code is 200, and rejecting directly non 200 Response Codes.

I feel with this approach the client side as well as SDK side the implementation would be more generic and straight forward.

Please correct me if I am wrong? Please shed some views.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Depends entirely on if you're exposing the API to external users for direct usage. If so, then I'd stick with sensible status codes. Having all endpoints return 200 regardless is IMHO even more misleading. If however, it's purely an internal API for a frontend you're building, then you can do whatever you like, as long as its correctly handled in the frontend.

Comment: So suppose I create the Client for my server then this approach is ok, right? And now coming to the 3rd party collaboration if I give them the SDK then at SDK level I will do the magic? Is this correct way of handling the stuff.?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no “REST standard”.

However, there is an [HTTP standard](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231), and the [original definition of REST](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm) emphasizes the notion of a [uniform interface](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm#sec_5_1_5) between the client and the server.

By using error codes according to the HTTP standard, you make your interface more uniform with other HTTP interfaces. This makes it possible to reuse more of existing HTTP client code when dealing with your API.

For example:

- Most clients automatically stop processing the response when they get an unexpected status code. If you always send 200 (OK), they need extra logic in order to not get confused.
- There are clients that can automatically retry requests when they receive [503 (Service Unavailable)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.6.4).
- There are clients that can [cache](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Caching) HTTP responses depending on their status code.

Note that nothing prevents you from sending a *custom* error code in the response payload, like in your example, **in addition to** a standard HTTP status code. (In fact, this is such a common practice that it has itself been standardized in [RFC 7807](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7807).)

Now, it’s perfectly possible that you don’t need a uniform interface. Maybe you’re building something internal, as the comments point out.

But if you don’t want a uniform interface, then you don’t want “REST” at all. Perhaps what you really need is an [RPC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_procedure_call) interface, such as [JSON-RPC](http://www.jsonrpc.org/) or [gRPC](https://grpc.io/).

Comment: Nice point, so with this approach, what should I return in case the login. If password mismatch or user ID not found in both case should I say 404?

Comment: @AnkurVerma No, [404](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.4) means “URL not found”. In case of authorization mismatch you should probably use [403 (Forbidden)](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.3), or [401 (Unauthorized)](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7235#section-3.1) if you’re using the [`WWW-Authenticate`](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7235#section-4) mechanism.

Comment: In any case, when you can’t find an exactly appropriate status code, you can fall back on [400](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1) for client errors and [500](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.6.1) for server errors.