# Do an error always needs to be rejected by a promise? Express route exception handling

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I have following route which gets some data and then stores in mongo db

router code

```
router.post('/addPatient',async (req,res)=>{
    let response = await patientRepo.addUser(req.body);
    res.send(response);
});
```

repository code

```
addUser = function(patientData){
    return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
        openDbConn().then((db)=>{
            let patient = new Patient(patientData);
            patient.save()
            .then(item=>  resolve(status.STATUS_CODES.PATIENT_SAVE_SUCCESS))
            .catch(err => resolve(status.STATUS_CODES.PATIENT_SAVE_FAILED))  /*see this line*/
            .finally(()=> db.close());
        }).catch(dbErr=> resolve(dbErr));    
    });
}
```

What I am doing is I am always resolving the promise from addUser function, even if it fails.
Because, If I will reject the promise, then in my router file, I have to change the route code like following to handle the rejected promise,

```
router.post('/addPatient',async (req,res,next)=>{
  try{
      let response = await patientRepo.addUser(req.body);
      res.send(response);
   }catch(err){
      next(err); /**This sends an html response generated by server for the error**/
   }
 });
```

The scenario is I want to send my custom codes to the client If in case of any exception, But on rejecting the promise the server responds with custom html page for server internal error 500.
But on resolve, I can pass the error description and code and hence no try catch required for the router code.

So is it ok, to go with this approach.Is it conventional? or ok?

Answer (score 1):

This question has a decent answer that I agree with:

- [Respond 200 with error or the response code as the error code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45499988/respond-200-with-error-or-the-response-code-as-the-error-code)

Essentially, as long as the client (UI) is aware that it needs to dig into the response, regardless of it's a `200 OK`, to potentially dig out an error code and/or condition, then this is perfectly legal to do so.

An alternative might be to not use the `next` functionality, which passes the error on automatically, but to manually set an error code, and then just return the JSON you'd like in the response object. In this case, you'd be using HTTP status codes "appropriately" while also providing the error object you want the client to consume.

```
router.post('/addPatient',async (req,res,next)=> {
  try{
      let response = await patientRepo.addUser(req.body);
      res.send(response);
   }catch(err){
      res.statusCode = 400;
      res.send(err);
   }
 });
```

That said, you'd need to `reject` in your `catch` statements in order for these to flow through of course.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 kinds of errors that might occur in your application:

1. Error due to some application-specific logic
2. Error raised by the server itself (DB error, File not found, etc.)

What I would suggest is the 1st type of error shouldn't return an HTTP code other than 200, as there is nothing wrong with your server. The second should return the appropriate code like 400, 500, 404, etc.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This kind of make sense, but in that case I want to send that 500 response in my custom error object, not with html template generated by the server due to a failed database connection, so that frontend can know these error codes/description too.

Comment: Are you doing an ajax from your application?

Comment: Yes, but I can ship the API too for others to use.

Comment: If you want to catch server errors and process and handle them yourself then i think you need to use try/catch.